# How to handle form validation and bulk editing with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.1.3. I'm trying to convert my existing application to a CI application. Is it possible to use the `form_validation` functions when bulk editing data? My current form is something like like this:

```
foreach($cash_flow as $key => $value) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="historical[<?php echo $value->id; ?>]" value="<?php echo set_value('historical['. $value->id .']', $value->historical); ?>" /></td>
    ...
</tr>
}
```

I have several other fields, but all of the input names are in array format with the record/row id in the brackets (`values->id`). According to the CI documentation, if I use arrays in input names, I have to use arrays in the validation rules as well. How would I do this? Would I need to create a loop (similar to above) and loop through my data and use the record id in the array brackets? Like this:

```
foreach($input_arr as $key) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('historical['. $key .']', 'Historical Value', 'required|clean_dec');
    ....
}
```

I tried that and it didn't work. It just output a CI validation error for each record saying the field was required. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: shouldnt your foreach be $input as $key => $value?

Comment: I wouldn't think so because the key is going to be the record id I set in the form ex: `name="historical[3608]"`.

Comment: assuming $input_arr = the posted historical array, if you want to set a rule on historical[3608] you need to do key => value in your foreach  for key to equal 3608.  otherwise key will be equal to the value of historical[3608]

Comment: Ah man I feel stupid--I completely missed. that. If you want to add this as an answer I'll vote it up and make it the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: no problem.  its easy to miss.  i just had to do a giant project with all these crazy multidimensional arrays so its fresh on my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller where you set your validation rules,
change your foreach to this:

```
foreach($input_arr as $key => $value):
```